# php regular expression minimum and maximum length doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, regex, max, minimum

I want to create a regular expression in PHP, which will allow to user to enter a phone number in either of the formats below.

345-234 898

345 234-898

235-123-456

548 812 346

The minimum length of number should be 7 and maximum length should be 12.

The problem is that, the regular expression doesn't care about the minimum and maximum length. I don't know what is the problem in it. Please help me to solve it. Here is the regular expression.

```
if (preg_match("/^([0-9]+((\s?|-?)[0-9]+)*){7,12}$/", $string)) {
echo "ok";
} else {
echo "not ok";
}
```

Thanks for reading my question. I will wait for responses.

Comment: How does phone number look if it has 12 digits? 7?

Comment: How about this one: $patten = "/\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{3}/";

Comment: What about `+1 800 123 4567`, `(800) 123 4567`, `18001234567`, etc.? There are so many ways to write a valid phone number. It's best to simply extract the digits from the user input string and validate from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use preg_replace to strip out non-digit symbols and check length of resulting string.

```
$onlyDigits = preg_replace('/\\D/', '', $string);
$length = strlen($onlyDigits);
if ($length < 7 OR $length > 12)
  echo "not ok";
else
  echo "ok";
```

Comment: +1 for best solution posted yet for validation, although I don't think you need to double escape. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is the best solution, however, the other answers are also good.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the start (^) and the end ($) sign on your pattern

```
$subject = "123456789";
    $pattern = '/^[0-9]{7,9}$/i';
    if(preg_match($pattern, $subject)){
        echo 'matched';
    }else{
        echo 'not matched';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3}$/", $string)) {
```

Here `\d` means any digits from `0-9`. Also `[ -]` means either a space or a hyphen

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length with a lookahead assertion `(?=...)` at the begining of the pattern:

```
/^(?=.{7,12}$)[0-9]+(?:[\s-]?[0-9]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your original regex, it can read like the following:

```
^                   # start of input
(
    [0-9]+          # any number, 1 or more times
    (
        (\s?|-?)    # a space, or a dash.. maybe
        [0-9]+      # any number, 1 or more times
    )*              # repeat group 0 or more times
)
{7,12}              # repeat full group 7 to 12 times
$                   # end of input
```

So, basically, you're allowing "any number, 1 or more times" followed by a group of "any number 1 or more times, 0 or more times" repeat "7 to 12 times" - which kind of kills your length check.

You could take a more restricted approach and write out each individual number block:

```
(
    \d{3}         # any 3 numbers
    (?:[ ]+|-)?   # any (optional) spaces or a hyphen
    \d{3}         # any 3 numbers
    (?:[ ]+|-)?   # any (optional) spaces or a hyphen
    \d{3}         # any 3 numbers
)
```

Simplified:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{3}(?:[ ]+|-)?\d{3}(?:[ ]+|-)?\d{3})$/', $string)) {
```

If you want to restrict the separators to be only a single space *or* a hyphen, you can update the regex to use `[ -]` instead of `(?:[ ]+|-)`; if you want this to be "optional" (i.e. there can be no separator between number groups), add in a `?` to the end of each.

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{3}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{3})$/', $string)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

may it help you out.

```
Validator::extend('price', function ($attribute, $value, $args) {
return preg_match('/^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$/', $value);
});
```